# Sublime - replace only certain area in file

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a file with hundreds of lines similar with this(different text):

```
<string key="$category_name jobs from $site_name"
<tr lang="ro">$ job_name_name de la $ site_name"

<string key="$companies_number Companies"
<tr lang="ro">$ companies_number Companii"
```

Somehow I need it to look like this everywhere:

```
<string key="$category_name jobs from $site_name">
<tr lang="ro">$ job_name_name de la $ site_name"</tr>
</string>
<string key="$companies_number Companies">
<tr lang="ro">$ companies_number Companii"</tr>
</string>
```

How can I achieve that ? I need to automatically close tr> , string>.

Comment: Sublime's search/replace fields accepts **multiline** input. That means you can actually search for your **whole** first chunk of code and replace it with the second **whole** chunk, including line breaks. Just make sure **Regex** option is not enabled.

Comment: I have hundreds of lines with different content, I just need to close the tags where need it.